# A function that would hide a specific <li> when the main <li> would be clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I've been developing a website with a simple book generator and I was even able to make two versions, one with a side list of books and one with a separate page (this one was much easier). I want to put more details for each book like a book it was published, genre, specifics, author etc. The problem is that my code already has like 50 list items and I have an idea for a function in JS that adds the CSS class display:none upon clicking and here's my question. Is there to do this without writing individual Ids for every separate list items and then creating 25 different functions?

```HTML
<div id="toggleMenu" class="sidebar-list-toggle" onclick="toggleMenu()">Open The Menu</div>
<nav id="menu" class="navbar">
  <ul id="nav_bookside" class="nav_books">
    <li class="nav-item">
      'Beze mnie jesteś nikim. Przemoc w polskich domach' by Jacek Hołób (2021) [nonfiction/difficult],<br>
    </li>
    <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
      <li>Written in 2021 by Jacek Hołób </li>
    </ul>
    <li class="nav-item">
      Frankenstein' by Mary Wollstonecraft Shelley (1818) [classics/dark],<br>
    </li>
    <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
      <li>Written in 1818 by Mary Wollstonecraft</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="nav-item">
      The house on the Mango Street' by Sandra Cisneros (1984) [feminism/emotional]
      <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
        <li>Written in 1984 by Sandra Cisneros </li>
      </ul>
      <li class="nav-item">
        These Ghosts Are Family' by Maisy Card (2020) [historical fiction/challenging
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2020 by Maisy Card</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'The Catcher in the Rye' by J.D Salinger (1951) [classics/reflective],<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 1951 by J.D Salinger</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Norwegian Wood' by Haruki Murakami (1987) [literary fiction/emotional],<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 1987 by Haruki Murakami</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Winter in Sokcho' by Elisa Shua Dusapin (2016) [literary fiction/emotional],<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2016 by Elisa Shua Dusapin</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Belonging: Remembering Ourselves Home' by Toko-Pa Turner (2017) [self-help/emotional]<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2017 by Toko-Pa Turner</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Strange Bedfellows' by Ina Park (2021) [science/challenging],<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2021 by Ina Park</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Circe' by Madeline Miller (2018) [historical fantasy/adventurous],<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2018 by Madeline Miller</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Red, White & Royal Blue' by Casey McQuiston (2019) [lgbtqia+/funny],<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2019 by Casey McQuiston</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Kim Jiyoung, Born 1982' by Cho Nam-Joo (2016) [feminism/informative],<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2016 by Cho Nam-Joo</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Aristotle 1' by Benjamin Alire Saenz (2012) [lgbtqia+/hopeful],<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2012 by Benjamin Alire Saenz</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'They Both Die at the End' by Adam Silvera (2017) [lgbtqia+/emotional],<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2017 by Adam Silvera </li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Ucieczka od bezradnosci' by Tomasz Stawiszyński (2021) [nonfiction/anticapitalism]<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2021 by Tomasz Stawiszyński</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Grown Ups' by Marie Gronbrog Aubert (2019) [fiction/funny],<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2019 by Marie Gronborg Aubert</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Men Explain Things to Me' by Rebecca Solnit (2013) [essays/reflective]<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2013 by Rebecca Solnit</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Klara and the Sun' by Kazuo Ishiguro (2021) [dystopian/emotional],<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2021 by Kazuo Ishiguro</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Komodo' by David Vann (2022) [fiction/contemporary],<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2022 by David Vann</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'The Mind of a Murderer' by Richard Taylor (2021) [nonfiction/true crime]<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2021 by Richard Taylor</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Czula przewodniczka' by Natalia de Barbaro (2021) [self-help/medium pace]<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2021 by Natalia de Barbaro</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Whats mine and yours' by Naima Coster (2021) [fiction/emotional],<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2021 by Naima Coster</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'The Japanese Devil' by Robert Rankin (2010) [fantasy-scifi/funny],<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2010 by Robert Rankin</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'The 7 Husbands of Evelynn Hugo' by Taylor Jenkins Reid (2017) [historical]<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2017 by Taylor Jenkins Reid</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Normal People' by Sally Rooney (2018) [fiction/emotional],<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2018 by Salley Rooney</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'The House in the Cerulean Sea' by Tj Klune (2020) [fantasy/adventurous]<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2020 by Tj Klune</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'Before the Coffee Gets Cold' by Toshikazu Kawaguchi (2015) [magical realism]<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2015 by Toshikazu Kawaguchi</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'The Housekeeper and the Professor' by Yoko Ogawa (2003) [literal/emotional]<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2003 by Yoko Ogawa</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          'A Manual for Being Human' by Dr Soph (2021) [nonfiction/reflective]<br>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav_books_sub" id="nav_bookside_sub">
          <li>Written in 2021 by Dr Soph</li>
        </ul>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you're looking to hide `<li>`s once they're clicked, you can add `onclick="this.style.display = 'none';"` to each `<li>` element.

Comment: @code I want to make it more like a submenu (the ones that you see on almost every website)

Comment: Your HTML is syntactically incorrect, that's why the answer "doesn't work". In HTML, one, and only one element may have a certain ID. If you want to share identifiers you can use HTML classes.

Comment: you are using the wrong tag for this kind of rendering, you must use the [`<details>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)

Comment: @code yeah what a brain fart, reusing Ids, I'll look into it now that I know which js code would help in achieving the result

Comment: **Your HTML is not valid**. You made `<ul>` **as direct child** of `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add a click handler to each list item, nor is it necessary to create a unique id for each element.

Because clicks on any element bubble up to the window, you can write just one click handler for all items.

This `window` click listener:

- receives all click events,
- determines which list item was clicked,
- toggles visibility of the next `nav_books_sub` element.

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  
  // get target that was clicked
  const el = ev.target;

  // if clicked element has class 'nav-item'
  if (el.classList.contains('nav-item')) {

    // get nav-item's next sibling
    const sub = el.nextElementSibling;

    // if next sibling exists and has class 'nav_books_sub'
    if (sub && sub.classList.contains('nav_books_sub')) {

      // toggle the 'hidden' class
      sub.classList.toggle('hidden');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav_bookside" class="nav_books">

  <li class="nav-item">'Beze mnie jesteś nikim. Przemoc w polskich domach' by Jacek Hołób (2021) [nonfiction/difficult], <br></li>
  <ul class="nav_books_sub">
    <li>Written in 2021 by Jacek Hołób </li>
  </ul>
  
  <li class="nav-item">Frankenstein' by Mary Wollstonecraft Shelley (1818) [classics/dark],<br></li>
  <ul class="nav_books_sub">
    <li>Written in 1818 by Mary Wollstonecraft</li>
  </ul>
  
  <li class="nav-item">The house on the Mango Street' by Sandra Cisneros (1984) [feminism/emotional]</li>
    <ul class="nav_books_sub">
      <li>Written in 1984 by Sandra Cisneros </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: The code only works on one or two of the lists...

Comment: @code there were typos in the copied HTML